# drag and drop working funny when using variable draggables and droppables

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

i have some containers that contain some divs like:

```
<div id="container1">
    <div id="task1" onMouseOver="DragDrop("+1+");">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task2" onMouseOver="DragDrop("+2+");">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task3" onMouseOver="DragDrop("+3+");">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task4" onMouseOver="DragDrop("+4+");">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="container2">
    <div id="task5" onMouseOver="DragDrop("+5+");">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task6" onMouseOver="DragDrop("+6+");">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="container3">
    <div id="task7" onMouseOver="DragDrop("+7+");">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task8" onMouseOver="DragDrop("+8+");">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task9" onMouseOver="DragDrop("+9+");">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task10" onMouseOver="DragDrop("+10+");">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

i'm trying to drag tasks and drop them in one of the container divs, then reposition the dropped task so that it doesn't affect the other divs nor fall outside one of them

and to do that i'm using the event onMouseOver to call the following function:

```
function DragDrop(id) {
           $("#task" + id).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
           for (var i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++) {
               $("#" + nameList[i]).droppable({
                   drop: function (ev, ui) {
                       var pos = $("#task" + id).position();
                       if (pos.left <= 0) {
                           $("#task" + id).css("left", "5px");
                       }
                       else {
                           var day = parseInt(parseInt(pos.left) / 42);
                           var leftPos = (day * 42) + 5;
                           $("#task" + id).css("left", "" + leftPos + "px");
                       }
                   }
               });

           }
       }
```

where:

```
nameList = [container1, container2, container3];
```

the drag is working fine, but the drop is not really, it's just a mess! 
any help please??
when i hardcode the id and the container, then it works beautifully, but as soon as i use id in drop then it begins to work funny!

any suggestions???
thanks a million in advance
Lina

Comment: Why are you initializing your draggables and droppables on mouseover event? Any particular reason?
I wonder if calling droppable multiple times (if you move the mouse over two divs for instance) is causing you problems.

Comment: ok, you have a good point there, but what if i have a 100 task divs?
should i write a draggable and droppable for each and every one of them?
or what is the solution in that case?

Comment: i took a step forward by removing onMouseOver event and using $("#container1").children() but still it is stable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider coding it like this:

```
<div id="container1" class="container">
    <div id="task1" class="task">1&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task2" class="task">2&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task3" class="task">3&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task4" class="task">4&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="container2" class="container">
    <div id="task5" class="task">5&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task6" class="task">6&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="container3" class="container">
    <div id="task7" class="task">7&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task8" class="task">8&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task9" class="task">9&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="task10" class="task">10&nbsp;</div>
</div>



$(function(){
  $(".task").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
  $(".container").droppable({
                   drop: function (ev, ui) {
                       //process dropped item
                   }
               });
})
```